# convert ajax get to post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am inserting data via AJAX, and sending the data using a GET request. Now I want to send the data using a POST request instead. How should I go about converting this code?

```
<form name=myf id=myf>
    <input type=text name=user>
    <input type=text name=email>
    <input type=button  onclick="ready();" value="Add">
</form>


<script languague=javascript>
    function ready(){           
        var url="adduser.php";
        var parm="?user="+document.myf.user.value;
        parm+="&email="+document.myf.email.value;
        //alert(parm);
        var target=document.getElementById('abc');
        add(url,parm,target);
        document.getElementById('myf').reset();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I see no Ajax code here. What does `add()` do? It's likely in there

Comment: may be showing code inside your add() function would help..!

Comment: Yes, your add function is important. Pls show it.

Comment: i am update short code. i am seding get in var url,pram,target.  code is too long so i cant paste here. add is sending a get to add data to database.

Comment: Why so many downvotes??? His title may be weird. For the new user we can provide some solutions instead of down voting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$.post(url, {'user':user, 'someotherdata':'data'}, function (response) {
    //do the result oriented activities
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        //Code after ajax response
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","adduser.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("user="+document.myf.user.value+"&email="+document.myf.email.value");
```